# Issue with POST email, returning to same page, templates and httpresponse

Tags: django

First of all, I only started using Django a week ago... so pretty new :).

I have a one page website. At the bottom there is a contact form. I am using different components for the website, so for the contact form I have 'contact.html' which is loaded into index.html via {& include ... &}. When someone sends a message via contact form, after click send, the user returns to the same page but with a thank you message instead of the contact form (see screenshot).

[image]

The issue is that I need to 'kill' the process going on underneath because if I reload the page a message pops and if I resubmit, email gets resend again (see screenshot).

[image]

I have had a look at httpresponse but I am unsure how to replicate the same process. Anyone could help?

This is a screenshot of contact.html and views.py

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

I would first consider using a front end framework such as react. (will make your life easier)

Secondly, your code seems fine, you are sending the email twice because you are submitting the form twice.
perhaps redirect the user to a different page upon submission. there is no need to reload the page yourself.

I would have a form, then a confirmation page.
Better yet, write an api, and upon response from the server simply create a popup saying success/fail etc...

Comment: It's good to hear I am doing things right lol. Do you mean REACT instead of DJANGO? Or do you mean in conjunction?

Comment: in conjunction. use react to handle backend stuff such (everything on the server) and React for the frontend (javascript framework)

Comment: also consider using django-rest-framework it will make your life much easier when handling models etc...

Comment: This is great help! Thanks for the advice. I will surely look at django rest framework